# Using boost::filesystem fails due to "_fchmodat" on mac

Tags: c++, macos, boost, filesystems

I want to use some functions of `boost::filesystem`.

I can include `boost/filesystem.hpp`and `boost/filesystem/path.hpp` without any problems, but as soon as I use some specific functions as `boost::filesystem::current_path()` or `boost::filesystem::initial_path()` I get the following compiler error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_fchmodat", referenced from:
boost::filesystem::detail::permissions(boost::filesystem::path const&,
boost::filesystem::perms, boost::system::error_code*) in 
libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I am linking against `-lboost-system` and `-lboost-filesystem` and I'm using `-std=c++0x` as compiler tag.

The version of **boost** is 1.56.0 installed via homebrew.

Edit: I also tried it using **boost 1.57.0** but the error is the same.

Comment: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/Q0J4Vq0ePh0JFYNnZ2bf

Comment: I just solved the problem. For some reason it was linked against **libboost-system.a** instead of **libboost-system.dylib** and the same for **libboost-filesystem**.

Comment: perhaps you can make this question worth something for others by self-answering. I'd +1 both actually

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This will be fixed in the upcoming Boost 1.60. My fix has already been committed to the [Boost.Filesystem develop branch](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/commit/5e5b529dc274cafc6a75beff1e1aac6b061a4fd1). You can also apply the [patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/10591/boost-fs-fchmodat-darwin.patch) to an earlier version of Boost.

**Original answer:**
This is a bug in Boost.Filesystem that is tracked as [Boost Ticket #10591](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10591). I ran into the same problem and developed a patch which I attached to the bug.

It'd be great if you could apply the patch to your copy of the Boost.Filesystem sources and report whether it now works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Boost bug to me. There should be no difference between linking statically vs. dynamically against these libraries. [Someone posted a fix here](http://ms-cheminfo.com/?q=node/90) but without explaining what's going on.

Note that the problem persists in Boost 1.58, the current version as of this writing.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously Qt Creator linked against `libboost-system.a` and `libboost-filesystem.a`. But on Mac OS X it should link against `libboost-system.dylib` and `libboost-filesystem.dylib`.

I changed this in the *.pro*-file by explicitly linking against the `.dylib`-libraries using `LIBS += "path/libboost-system.dylib"`. This fixed the problem.

Comment: Unless the dynamic and static libraries were built using different versions of boost (the versions with and without this issue) changing the linking options will not fix the root problem.